# What can I do to fix a PC that won't run its bios?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios

I have a Win 7 home premium PC that has been giving me trouble with the bios.  I've noticed when different devices (ipod, iphone, external hard drives, etc.) are plugged in or taken off the system, and then it's rebooted, the computer will often hang on reboot, and it's not getting to the point where the bios loads.  I can't, for example, press the usual key to enter bios configuration.  My suspicion is that b/c it's happening b/c of random devices being plugged in or not that there's something related to the plug-and-play system that's haywire, but I'm really at a  loss.  Anyone have any suggestions for directions that I could take to try to fix this thing?

Answer (score 1):

**@Jeff,**

There could be some issues or device conflicts going on with the USB controllers.  The bios on some motherboards have the option of letting the bios or the operating system control the USB.  If your motherboard has that option make sure it is set to os.  Also make sure the drivers and bios for your mb are all up to date.

If you have problems getting in to your bios you might have to reset the motherboard by removing the battery and moving some jumpers depending on the model.

A good general system health and diagnostic program is [Everest by Lavalys](http://www.lavalys.com/) They have trial versions available.

If resetting the motherboard doesn't help you can reflash the bios by creating a bootable USB drive with the latest bios.  Your mb manufacture should have the everything you need to do that on their website.

Comment: I see this A LOT with external usb hard drives - for some reason especially with Seagate.  My Western Digitals don't seem to slow the boot, but attach a SG drive and sometimes it fails to complete boot and won't even get to the BIOS setup screen.